# I am attempting to deploy a Django app via AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I have run into errors of every kind. Now I'm getting a connection error

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am following the W3 Django tutorial at this site: https://www.w3schools.com/django/django_deploy_provider.php. I'm hoping to get a sample deployment working here. Then, I'll be able to deploy my actual application.

As you can see, the environment is setup and the health is ok.

[image: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment]

Here is the page when you go to it.  As you can see, it displays correctly. So at least something is working correctly.

[image: The website]

When I click on the members link, I get this page after waiting for a while:

[image: The Error]

I've looked in the logs and found the following in the errors section:

---

### /var/log/nginx/error.log

023/08/24 07:44:55 [error] 3217#3217: *6 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 64.71.154.2, server: , request: "GET /members/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/members/", host: "my-tennis-club-env-new.eba-gysp36xc.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://my-tennis-club-env-new.eba-gysp36xc.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/"

I figured that the problem must be the fact that it's making an HTTP GET request to the localhost. I don't know why this would be. In the Django settings file I have ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['my-tennis-club-env-new.eba-gysp36xc.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com']. This should solve that problem but it doesn't. I still get the time outs.

Please help me with this issue. This is my first Django project and deployment is much more difficult than I expected.

Comment: Looks like it's not the problem of ALLOWED_HOSTS. Check once, what URL you have given to members link.

Comment: Here is the urls.py file inside the application "members" folder:

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.main, name='main'),
    path('members/', views.members, name='members'),
    path('members/details/<int:id>', views.details, name='details'),
    path('testing/', views.testing, name='testing')
]

Comment: Here is the urls.py folder inside the "my_tennis_club" folder:

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('members.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

Comment: Note that everything works fine on localhost. Please help.

Comment: Are you using jinja template language?

Comment: I resolved this.  Thanks for the follow up though.

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: Don't even know.  I paid someone to complete it.  But the issue is closed.